# How can I use padding right when it is floating right already?

Tags: html, css

I have two images one on the left margin and one on the right margin. I want to center the two elements so they meet in the middle.

But since the box I have on the right is floating right to align to the left one, my padding right doesn't work to push it.

[I want to center these two things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yxsR.png)

Here is my code:

```
<section id="content1">
  <a href="#"><img src="images/matcha.jpg" alt="pic1" width="300" height="300" /></a>

  <div class="box1">
    <div class="heading1">
      <p>GREEN TEA LOVE</p>
    </div>

    <div class="paragraph1">
      <p>Top Impression Bakery Cafe has been on my go-to list for awhile since I saw their 
        Green Tea Croissant on Instagram. If you know me well you would know that I'm a huge 
        fan of anything Matcha and if anything is Matcha related I've got to try it!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#content1{
   padding-top:50px;
   padding-bottom:30px;
   width: 960px;
}

.box1{
   width:500px;
   height:300px;
   background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #77ebcf 20%, #ffffff 20%); 
   border-style:solid;
   float:right;
}
```

Comment: I only see one image and the `<img>` tag should not have a closing slash.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need to float the right box to "align it to the left one". You can use `vertical-align` on the image to get them vertically aligned. In order to get them centered, you just need to add `text-align: center` to `#content1`. See https://jsfiddle.net/8gkcguwb/1/.

Comment: If you want them to be aligned in the middle of the page remove the width from `#content1`.

Comment: You can also add `margin: auto` to `#content1` if you need it to be a specific width.

Comment: ah thank you for taking the time to explain, still getting used to it!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried both elements #content and .box1 to

margin 0 auto;

Answer (score 0):

Use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on your parent content section tag, remove the floating on the box. You can change the justify-content rule to space-around so it can be distributed based on the width of the parent as well as a flex wrap to wrap if the window resizes.

```css
#content1{
   padding-top:50px;
   padding-bottom:30px;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 960px;
   display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box1{
   width:500px;
   height:300px;
   background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #77ebcf 20%, #ffffff 20%); 
   border-style:solid;
   
}
```

```html
<section id="content1">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" alt="pic1" width="300" height="300" /></a>

  <div class="box1">
    <div class="heading1">
      <p>GREEN TEA LOVE</p>
    </div>

    <div class="paragraph1">
      <p>Top Impression Bakery Cafe has been on my go-to list for awhile since I saw their 
        Green Tea Croissant on Instagram. If you know me well you would know that I'm a huge 
        fan of anything Matcha and if anything is Matcha related I've got to try it!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cagx0p4x/)